# Issue with using protobufs with python ImportError: cannot import name descriptor_pb2

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

**Context**

Steps taken:

*Environment Setup*

- I've installed protobufs via `Home Brew`
- I've also followed the steps in the proto-bufs python folder's readme on installing python protobufs - namely running the `python setup.py install` command
- I've using the `protobuf-2.4.1` files

*Coding*

- I have a python file (generated from a .proto file I compiled) that contains the statement, among other import statements, but I believe this one is the one causing issues:

  `from google.protobuf import descriptor_pb2`
- The above python file, I'm importing in another python file, it's
  this python file that I want to write up logic for parsing the
  protobufs data files I receive

**Error received**

I get this error when running that file:

[image]

**Steps taken to fix**

- Searched google for that error - didn't find much
- Looked at this question/answer [Why do I see "cannot import name descriptor_pb2" error when using Google Protocol Buffers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828379/why-do-i-see-cannot-import-name-descriptor-pb2-error-when-using-google-protoco)
- I don't really understand the above questions selected answer,I tried to run the command in the above answer `protoc descriptor.proto --python_out=gen/` by coping and pasting it in the terminal in different places but couldn't get it to work

**Question**

- How do I fix this error?
- What is the underlying cause?
- How do I check if the rest of my protobuf python compiler/classes are set up correctly?

Comment: I do not use python version of Protocol Buffers. In java, descriptor is distributed as a proto file and converted to Java classes via protoc (as part of the Java build process). Have a look at the classes generated when you did the python install. (For Java you do both a C build and a Java build, Python is the same).

Comment: I don't really understand your comment? What solution are you proposing?

Comment: If it is like jave, descripto_pb should of been created when you did the protocol-buffer python install.

Answer (score 1):

I've discovered the issue. I had not run the python install instructions the first time I tried to compile this file. I recompiled the file and this issue was fixed.

Comment: So what did you do to fix it?